# Tensor product commutes with direct limits

Tags: tensor-products, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $(A_n, \phi_n)$ be an inductive system of $C^*$ algebras and let $B$ be an arbitary $C^*$ algebra.
Is it true that $(\varinjlim A_n)\otimes B \cong \varinjlim (A_n \otimes B)$? 
I'm using the notation $\otimes$ for the spatial norm.

If not, please give me a counterexample, 
but if it is true let me prove this by myself...

 Thank you!

Comment: I think they are. Post your proof!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $(A_n,\varphi_{n+1,n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be an inductive system of $C^*$-algebras with faithful connecting maps and let $B$ be an arbitrary $C^*$ algebra. Then $(\varinjlim A_n)\otimes B \cong \varinjlim (A_n\otimes B)$.

*Remark:* If the connecting maps are not faithful, the claim is not true.

*Proof:* Denote by $(A,\{\varphi^n\})$ the inductive limit of $A_1\xrightarrow{\varphi_{2,1}} A_2 \xrightarrow{\varphi_{3,2}}A_3 \xrightarrow{\varphi_{4,3}}\ldots$. For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have a unique $*$-homomorphism $\varphi_{n+1,n}\otimes id_B:A_n\otimes B \to A_{n+1}\otimes B$ such that $(\varphi_{n+1,n}\otimes id_B)(a\otimes b)=\varphi_{n+1,n}(a)\otimes b$ for all $a\in A_n, b\in B$.

As $\varphi_{n+1,n}$ and $id_B$ are injective for all $n$, also $\varphi_{n+1,n}\otimes id_B$ is faithful (By exercises 3.3.5 and 3.4.1 - Brown&Ozawa).

We have an inductive system
$$A_1\otimes B \xrightarrow{\varphi_{2,1}\otimes id} A_2\otimes B \xrightarrow{\varphi_{3,2}\otimes id}A_3\otimes B \xrightarrow{\varphi_{4,3}\otimes id}\ldots$$ Denote by $(C, \{\psi^n\})$ the inductive limit.
We need to show that $C\cong A\otimes B$.

For all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have a commutative diagram:
[image]

(We check it commutes by verifying it on elementary tensors and then using linearity and continuity).
By the universal property of inductive limits there exists a unique $*$-homomorphism $\lambda:C\to A\otimes B$ making the diagram:
[image]

commutative. It is left to show that $\lambda$ is a $*$-isomorphism.

$\lambda$ is injective: We have $C=\overline{\cup_n{\psi^n(A_n\otimes B)}}$ and $A=\overline{\cup_n{\varphi^n(A_n)}}$. It suffices to check that $\lambda$ is injective on each $\psi^n(A_n\otimes B)$.
But, $\overline{\psi^n(A_n\odot B)}=\psi^n(A_n\otimes B)$. So, it suffices to show $\lambda$ is isometric on $\psi^n(A_n\odot B)$, and this is immediate by the commutativity of the diagram and the fact that $\varphi^n\otimes id$ is isometric.

$\lambda$ is surjective: As the range of $\lambda$ is closed, it suffices for any $\epsilon>0$ and $y\in A\otimes B$ to find $x\in C$ s.t. $||\lambda(x)-y||<\epsilon$. So, let $z\in A\odot B$ be s.t. $||z-y||_{min}<\epsilon/2$.

Write $z=\sum_{i=1}^{m} s_i\otimes b_i$, where $s_i\in A$ and $b_i\in B$.

We can find some $n$ and $a_1,...,a_m\in A_n$ s.t. 
$||\varphi^n(a_i)-s_i||<\frac{\epsilon}{2 max_i{||b_i||} m}$ for all $1\leq i\leq m$.

Therefore, $||z-\sum_{i=1}^{m} \varphi^n(a_i)\otimes b_i||=||\sum_{i=1}^{m}(s_i-\varphi^n(a_i))\otimes b_i||\leq \sum_{i=1}^{m} ||s_i-\varphi^n(a_i)|| ||b_i||<\epsilon/2$.

Combining the two, we have: $||y-\sum_{i=1}^{m} \varphi^n(a_i)\otimes b_i||<\epsilon$ and $\lambda(\psi^n(\sum_{i=1}^{m} a_i\otimes b_i))=\varphi^n\otimes id (\sum_{i=1}^{m} a_i\otimes b_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{m} \varphi^n(a_i)\otimes b_i$ ,
as required.

I hope my solution is correct, any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Good job. Without thinking much about it, it is not obvious to me that if $\lambda$ is one-to-one in a dense set, then it has to be one-to-one. But isometric on a dense subset, on the other hand, does the trick and that's what you proved.

Comment: If the connecting maps are not injective Blackadar says that this is not necessarily true. See "Operator Algebras: Theory of C*-Algebras and von Neumann Algebras,  Bruce Blackadar, II.9.6.5"

Comment: Thank you, I edited my answer :)

Comment: Indeed, good job! Note that one can proof that the suspension functor for $C^*$-algebras is continuous in a very similar way. I guess that the only difference is the injectivity of $\lambda$ since the connecting maps are not faithful in general. How to handle the injectivity is described here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/82090/when-do-tensor-products-of-c-algebras-commute-with-colimits

Comment: @toto Good comment. If you want to show continuity of the suspension functor, using tensor products, i.e. $C_0(\Bbb{R})\otimes A =SA$ , then note that $C_0(\Bbb{R})$ is a nuclear $C^*$-algebra. My answer is working for minimal tensor product and injective connecting maps. However, the claim for maximal tensor product is always true (this is using the face that maximal tensor products are always exact), so you don't need injectivity of the connecting maps in case $B$ (with notations as in answer) is nuclear, or exact.