# Norm on inductive limit

Tags: tensor-products, c-star-algebras

Let $(A_i,\Phi_{ij})$ be an inductive system of $C^*$-algebras with inductive limit $A$. Let $B$ be another $C^\ast$-algebra.

I want to show that for the minimal tensor product we have $\mathrm{lim}(A_i\otimes B)=A\otimes B$.

Clearly we have an isomorphism $\mathrm{lim}(A_i\odot B)\cong A\odot B$ on the algebraic tensor product. I want to show that this extends to an isomorphism of $C^\ast$-algebras with respect to the norm of the minimal tensor product on $A\otimes B$ and the induced norm on the limit $\mathrm{lim}(A_i\otimes B)$. In other words: the induced norm on the inductive limit is the norm of the minimal tensor product.

Can somebody help? What does the induced norm look like?

Comment: For inductive limits over $\mathbb N$ with injective connecting maps this is proven here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1972645/tensor-product-commutes-with-direct-limits. That it is not necessarily true if the connecting maps are not injective is also remarked in one of the comments (the reference is there).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not true in general and the reason is that the minimal tensor product functor $-\otimes B$ is not necessarily exact. In contrast to that, the *maximal* tensor product functor $-\otimes_\max B$ is exact, and this allows one to conclude continuity with respect to inductive limits; see [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381936/the-maximal-tensor-product-is-a-continuous-functor).

In the case that $B$ is an exact $C^*$-algebra, i.e. $-\otimes B$ preserves short exact sequences, then what you claim is true. Let's see how this works:

Let $A_1\xrightarrow{\phi_1}A_2\xrightarrow{\phi_2}A_3\to\dots$ be an inductive system with inductive limit $(A,\{\mu_n\}_{n\ge1})$. For $m\ge n$, put $\varphi_{m,n}:=\varphi_m\circ\varphi_{m-1}\circ\dots\circ\varphi_n:A_n\to A_m$. Tensoring with $B$, we have the inductive system
$$A_1\otimes B\xrightarrow{\phi_1\otimes\mathrm{id}_B}A_2\otimes B\xrightarrow{\phi_2\otimes\mathrm{id}_B}\dots$$
and note that the pair $(A\otimes B,\{\mu_n\otimes\mathrm{id}_B\}_{n\ge1})$ satisfies $(\mu_n\otimes\mathrm{id}_B)=(\varphi_n\circ\mu_{n+1})\otimes\mathrm{id}_B=(\varphi_n\otimes\mathrm{id}_B)\circ(\mu_{n+1}\otimes\mathrm{id}_B)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. So, all we need to do is verify the following two conditions:

1. $A\otimes B=\overline{\bigcup_n(\mu_n\otimes\mathrm{id}_B)(A_n\otimes B)}$
2. $\ker(\mu_n\otimes\mathrm{id}_B)=\{x\in A_n\otimes B: \lim_{m\to\infty}\|\varphi_{m,n}\otimes\mathrm{id}_B(x)\|=0\}$ for all $n\ge1$.

If it is not clear why this suffices, I recommend looking at chapter 6 of Rordam's blue book. The first condition is easily verified by some density arguments. For the second condition, the inclusion of the right-hand-side inside the left-hand-side is easy (why: take $x\in A_n\otimes B$ with $\lim_m\|\varphi_{m,n}\otimes\mathrm{id}_B(x)\|=0$. Then $\|\mu_n\otimes\mathrm{id}_B(x)\|=\|(\varphi_{m,n}\otimes\mathrm{id}_B\circ(\mu_m\otimes\mathrm{id}_B)(x)\|\le\|\varphi_{m,n}\otimes\mathrm{id}_B(x)\|$ for all $m>n$, so letting $m\to\infty$ yields that $\|\mu_n\otimes\mathrm{id}_B(x)\|=0$). For the other inclusion, we use exactness of $B$: let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and consider the short exact sequence $0\to\ker(\mu_n)\xrightarrow{\iota}A_n\xrightarrow{\pi}\mu_n(A_n)\to0$ (where $\iota$ is the inclusion map and $\pi$ is the corestriction of $\mu_n$, i.e. $\pi:A_n\to\mu_n(A_n)$ defined as $\pi(a)=\mu_n(a)$). By tensoring with $B$, we obtain a short exact sequence $0\to\ker(\mu_n)\otimes B\xrightarrow{\iota\otimes\mathrm{id}_B}A_n\otimes B\xrightarrow{\pi\otimes\mathrm{id}_B}\mu_n(A_n)\otimes B\to0$. By exactness, we have that $\ker(\pi\otimes\mathrm{id}_B)=\text{Im}(\iota\otimes\mathrm{id}_B)$.

Consider the inclusion map $j:\mu_n(A_n)\to A$ (which is injective). Since $\otimes$ preserves injectivity, we have that $j\otimes\mathrm{id}_B:\mu_n(A_n)\otimes B\to A\otimes B$ is injective. Now $\mu_n\otimes\mathrm{id}_B=(j\circ\pi)\otimes\mathrm{id}_B=(j\otimes\mathrm{id}_B)\circ(\pi\otimes\mathrm{id}_B)$, and since $j\otimes\mathrm{id}_B$ is injective, we have that $\ker(\mu_n\otimes\mathrm{id}_B)=\ker(\pi\otimes\mathrm{id}_B)=\text{Im}(\iota\otimes\mathrm{id}_B)$.

It suffices to show that $\iota\otimes\mathrm{id}_B(y)$ belongs to the RHS of condition 2 for all $y\in\ker(\mu_n)\otimes B$ -- and it further suffices to show this for elementary tensors, since these generate the tensor product as a $C^*$-algebra. So let $a\in\ker(\mu_n)$ and $b\in B$. Since $(A,\{\mu_n\})$ is by assumption the inductive limit of $(A_j,\phi_j)$, we have that $\ker(\mu_n)=\{a\in A_n: \lim_{m\to\infty}\|\varphi_{m,n}(a)\|=0\}$. Now
$$\|(\varphi_{m,n}\otimes\mathrm{id}_B)(a\otimes b)\|_{A_m\otimes B}=\|\varphi_{m,n}(a)\otimes b\|=\|\varphi_{m,n}(a)\|\cdot\|b\|\xrightarrow[m\to\infty]{}0$$

and we are done.

Comment: Thank you. How do you get $||\varphi_{m,n}(a)\otimes b||=||\varphi_{m,n}(a)||\cdot||b||$? Furthermore can one generalize this to arbitrary directed colimits? And you used that the connecting maps are injective to be able to build the union, right?

Comment: @Roland It is known that every $C^*$-norm on $A\odot B$ (the algebraic tensor product) is a cross-norm, i.e. $\|x\otimes y\|=\|x\|\cdot\|y\|$ for all elementary tensors. This follows from the fact that the spatial norm has this property and that this is the minimal norm. I did not use injectivity of the connecting maps, I prove that exact $C^*$-algebras have continuous minimal tensor products in general (if you suspect injectivity has been used somewhere let me know).  I am not sure about generalizing to arbitrary directed colimits, I can't take a guess.

Comment: I see that $||x\otimes y||=||x||\cdot ||y||$ holds for the minimal tensor product. Using that any other norm on elementary tensors can be estimated by the minimal tensor product norm I expect to get $||x\otimes y||\geq ||x\otimes y||_{\mathrm{min}}=||x||\cdot||y||$ and no equality in general.

Comment: @Roland no, you always get equality and this is well-known. Here is an argument for the unital case: take $\|\cdot\|_\alpha$ any c-star norm on $A\odot B$.  We have $\|a\otimes b\|=\|(a\otimes 1_B)(1_A\otimes b)\|\le\|a\otimes 1_B\|\cdot\|1_A\otimes b\|$ so it suffices to see that $\|a\otimes 1_B\|=\|a\|$. But indeed, the map $A\to A\otimes_\alpha B$ given by $a\mapsto a\otimes 1_B$ is an injective $*$-homomorphism, hence isometric. This proves the other inequality. There is a non-unital argument as well.